# Backbone custom model get

Tags: backbone.js

I'd like one of my getters to return a minimum value of the model's collection, is it possible to have a model getter function? Reason I need this is so I can easily have my models rendered in a template using `toJSON`.

Comment: look into the min method that comes with underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/#min

Comment: have you seen  [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147969/saving-jquery-ui-sortables-order-to-backbone-js-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Are these minimum values just defaults to fill in, if there is nothing else?

If so. you can define the defaults on the model

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        attrA: 'attr a default',
        attrB: 'attr b default'
    }
});
```

Comment: not defaults, at any given time i'd like to be able to get a value based on some criteria via getter, ie a getter as a function

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the defaults you can override the `get` method if you need more control.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   get: function (attr) {
      if (attr === 'my_attribute')
      {
         return this.getMyAttribute();
      }

      return Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
   },
   getMyAttribute: function() {
      var result = Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
      if (typeof result === "undefined" || result < 0) return 0;
      return result;
   }
});
```