# Backbone.js view listen to jquery ui events

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm trying to get a backbone.js view to listen for an event from jquery-ui sortable.  The `update` event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

Here's what my view looks like:

```
var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#products',

    initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render','addOne', 'sortChanged');

            this.listenTo(app.collection.filteredProducts, 'reset', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.$el, 'update', this.sortChanged);

            this.$el.sortable();

    },

    render: function(){

            this.$el.html('');

            this.collection.each(function(product){
                    this.addOne(product);
            }, this);

            return this;
    },

    addOne: function(product){
            var view = new ProductItemView({model: product});
            this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    },

    sortChanged: function(){
            alert('changed');
    }

});
```

I thought that `this.$el` would emit an `update` event since that is the same element sortable is applied to.  However, I'm not getting any alerts after adjusting the sort of the list, so it seems like the event is not being fired the way I would have expected.

I have read this post:

[Saving jQuery UI Sortable's order to Backbone.js Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147969/saving-jquery-ui-sortables-order-to-backbone-js-collection)

That method seems to work, but I would like to understand why this method does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the views events.

```
var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#products',
    events: {
        sortupdate: 'sortChanged'
    },
    ...
});
```

According to [the jQueryUI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), the event name is actually, "sortupdate". You can add the listener one of two ways.

**Code examples:**

Initialize the sortable with the update callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bind an event listener to the sortupdate event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "sortupdate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: Wow that worked. It does not work if I use the listenTo method rather than the view events, though.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: not sure. It might have to do with the order of operations.